# Matplotlib: scatter.legend_elements() not as 1,2,3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

This is DataFrame:

```
   age    weight   score  height     name
0  12     100      12      501         aa  
1  23     120      12      502         bb
2  34     121      13      499         bb
3  32     134      10      499         cc
4  23     133      11      498         cc
5  12     112      19      503         aa
```

I need to do a four scatter graphs for columns: 'age', 'weight','score','height' , so my code:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(12,8))
property = ['age','weight','score','height']
indexes = df.index.tolist()
for counter in range(0,4):    
    i = counter % 2
    j = math.floor(counter / 2)     
    scatter = axes[i,j].scatter(indexes,df[property[counter]],c=y)  
    axes[i,j].set_title(property[counter])
    legend = axes[i,j].legend(*scatter.legend_elements())
    axes[i,j].add_artist(legend)
```

As result i got labels as '1','2','3'
How to get labels as 'aa','bb','cc' and with different colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn could create the legends automatically:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''   age    weight   score  height     name
0  12     100      12      501         aa  
1  23     120      12      502         bb
2  34     121      13      499         bb
3  32     134      10      499         cc
4  23     133      11      498         cc
5  12     112      19      503         aa'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 8))
property = ['age', 'weight', 'score', 'height']
indexes = df.index.tolist()
for ax, prop in zip(axes.ravel(), property):
    scatter = sns.scatterplot(x=indexes, y=prop, hue='name', data=df, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(prop)
    ax.set_ylabel('')  # remove default y label
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]